# Getting extents of spatial reference system using Proj.4?

Tags: coordinate-system, proj, geopackage

In general, how does one get the valid extents of a spatial reference system but in particular, is there a way using the Proj.4 library?

I attempted to use the information from the epsg.io website, but to the best of my understanding the bounds are not quite right.  For example, for EPSG:3857 the vertical extents are stated as from latitude -85.06 deg to 85.06 deg.  But the correct extents should be closer to -85.0511288 to 85.0511288.  I realize that the "corners" in one SRS may not carry over to another, because straight-line-boundaries can transform to curves, but I can't get the 85.0511288 value using the extents given in the Projected Bounds section either.

In this particular case I could, naturally, look the answer up elsewhere, but I have failed to find a source that provides these extents for, say, all EPSG-provided spatial reference systems.

My need for the precise extents is related to an efficient tiling algorithm for geopackage-format tile pyramids.  Unfortunately it seems that geopackage doesn't provide the spatial reference extents.

Comment: Most official reference that exists is probably the EPSG registry. You can browse it at http://epsg-registry.org/ or download the whole database. For EPSG:3857 the Area Description seems to be just "World between 85.06°S and 85.06°N.". What reference did you use for values  -85.0511288 to 85.0511288?

Comment: In the EPSG registry, the Area of Use section does indeed provide those values. If you click "Metadata" to the far right of of the "Area of Use" section header, under "Remarks" it's given: 

"Web map tile service latitude limit is +/- 85.05112878°."

This is provided as a remark and is not in a standardized, machine-readable form, nor does this kind of remark appear consistently for different projections.  The 85.0511... number corresponds to other sources, as well, and is the only number that works empirically when dealing with EPSG 3857 tiles.

Answer (score 2):

The EPSG database http://epsg-registry.org/ contains also "Area of Use" descriptions. From the documentation:

> Area of Use
>
> The area of use is a description of the geographic applicability of
>   certain entities. It is applied toCoordinate Reference Systems, Datums
>   and Coordinate Operations (Conversions, including Map Projections,and
>   Transformations).
>
> The primary information is a brief written description of the area of
>   applicability for this record. Exceptfor some records having global or
>   continental applicability the description will include country name(s)
>   asgiven in ISO 3166 (English version).
>
> ISO country codes
>
> 2-character and 3-character long codes and a numeric (integer) code as
>   defined in ISO 3166. They arepopulated only for the countries as
>   defined in that international standard.
>
> Bounding Box Boundary
>
> This is an approximate maximum and minimum geographic extent of the
>   area.
>
> If the area is a north-orientated rectangle this will be a good
>   approximation to the coordinate range. Forirregular shapes the
>   bounding Box Boundary will include significant territory that is
>   outside of the area.
>
> If the area crosses the 180-degree meridian, the westernmost value
>   will be greater thanthe easternmost value. Longitudes are shown as +/-
>   180 degrees.
>
> The bounding latitude and longitude values are nominally referenced to
>   the WGS 84 CRS.
>
> Area polygons
>
> The area boundary can also be described in a separate file that
>   contains polygon coordinates. Referenced filesuse Geography Markup
>   Language (GML) format. These Polygon entities are also available
>   through the registry(although not managed directly by the Registry
>   Application) and can be accessed via the associated Area ofUse entity.

Comment: In the EPSG registry, the Area of Use section does indeed provide those values. If you click "Metadata" to the far right of of the "Area of Use" section header, under "Remarks" it's given: 

"Web map tile service latitude limit is +/- 85.05112878°."

This is provided as a remark and is not in a standardized, machine-readable form, nor does this kind of remark appear consistently for different projections.  The 85.0511... number corresponds to other sources, as well, and is the only number that works empirically when dealing with EPSG 3857 tiles.

Comment: All right, those adjusted limits seem to be there because the Google tiling schema has fixed tile sizes and resolutions. I suppose that most projection definitions are much older than the tiling schemata of Google and others and Area of Use may not match any tile boundaries.

Comment: From the documentation excerpt that you provided, would you infer that every projection has a definite area of geographic applicability?  If so, it is then unfortunate that EPSG itself only provides an approximate area of applicability, unless I'm missing something.  I don't know whether more blame falls upon EPSG, or the tile source providers (I'm dealing with various projections and not just EPSG 3857), or myself if there is an answer that I'm missing.  But at the moment it seems to me that the answer to my question is "There is no way." ...

Comment: (From the documentation that you provided: "This is an **approximate** maximum and minimum geographic extent of the area.")  I understand that the exact extents may not be expressible in lat/lon bounding box, but I would hope that they would be expressible in **some** coordinate system.

Comment: Probably exact usage areas are not reasonable. There tends to be always some lake or country or parcel that gets split by such boundaries and benefit of presenting the whole area in one system may be bigger that the trouble with increased distortions etc.

Comment: EPSG subcommittee member here: there are polygon boundaries that are more accurate, but the goal (on the envelopes) to use around 2 decimal places in lat/lon. Get more accurate/precise and you have to start dealing with the GeoCRS/datum as well.